# Is it possible to have a split personality like those seen in the movies?

Tags: psychology

Has there ever been any people who existed from split personality disorder like those seen in movies? In the sense they had more than one coherent, distinct personalities (and weren't biopolar or another condition)?

Comment: Are references on wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociative_identity_disorder not enough?